# How to have full page <img> that is not a background img or fixed positioned?

Tags: html, css

There's so much information about how to have full page background images, but I can't work out how to achieve the same effect with `<img>` tags and **no fixed positioning**.

Yes, I have read the CSS tricks article on [full page backgrounds](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

In my image below the red border is the viewport.  Each image is part of an `<article>`.  I want the effect of `background-size: cover` but using an actual `<img>` tag.

[image]

Example HTML:

```
<article>
  <figure class="bg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
  </figure>
</article>
<article>
  <figure class="bg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
  </figure>
</article>
```

[This CSS tricks technique (technique number 2)](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) has the effect I want, but it relies upon the fixed positioning and I can't get it to work without that:

```
article {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}

.bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

The image needs to be centered inside it's container too (horizontally).

**[Here's a fiddle using the fixed technique.](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/NNQ3A/11/)**

Comment: Interesting, why can't you use a CSS background? So the background image isn't just decoration?

Comment: Might [this page](http://ciphertext.info/misc/photo_album/#/test/1) be a useful example?  It doesn't make the photo full-screen, but if you expand the dimensions of `contentPanel` and `photo`, it should work at full screen.

Comment: I do not understand why you would want to achieve something by denying yourself the tools designed to allow you to achieve it.  What is the purpose of these apparently-arbitrary restrictions?

Comment: @JeremyMiller they're not 'arbitrary' at all.  My image is part of the content, it's not a background image used for decoration.  The article will have a header and text and then the image.  It just so happens I want that image to be the full size of the viewport.

Comment: Ah, well, tbh, that description of your question is much more useful... instead of saying what cannot be done, you're defining what needs to be achieved.  Thanks! (Curiously, if it's the full width of the viewport, then what does "centered inside its container too (horizontally)" imply?  I guess I'm just not visualizing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry if there was confusion.  Essentially I want this:  http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/NNQ3A/5/ but I want the images to be the full height and width, irrespective of browser size, and maintain proportion (like `background: cover` would do).  The red and blue represent 2 different articles.  By 'centered inside its container' I mean the same effect that `background-position: 50%` would have, except I don't have that luxury.

Comment: Why did the question get downvoted?

Comment: I downvoted b/c it seemed that the question wasn't well-put or helpful to anyone.  Since your clarifications, though, I have reversed my thinking and negated my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah it was actually simple.  Just had to use absolute instead of fixed and have the parent (`article`) relative with hidden overflow.

```
article {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/NNQ3A/14/

Comment: Amazing how little needs to be changed. Try it with that jQuery plugin, would be neat.

Comment: Always the way!  Looked straight to more complicated things. Will try the plugin, thanks for the tip and your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

[Could something like this be what you're looking for or am I way off?](http://jsfiddle.net/NNQ3A/15/)

```
article {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

article img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not quite, as I don't want any horizontal scrolling. Also, I need the articles to stack, so you can scroll down to the next article, which would also fit the full page.

Comment: Updated the answer (and JSFiddle). Getting closer?

Comment: I think possible getting further way :/ - It doesn't cover the viewport (only in width).

Comment: I guess what I'm not understanding is if you want different backgrounds for articles which are stacked vertically after another, how could each background cover the entire height of the viewport? Should their height not depend on their content?

Comment: So it's this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/NNQ3A/9/ but instead of having different colours, I want an actual `<img>` element to fill the space.  So the red would be the first article image, the blue would be the second article image.  And that can go on down the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start I think... actually isn't this exactly what you want?

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/UN5j5/)

HTML

```
<article>
  <figure class="bg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
  </figure>
</article>
<article>
  <figure class="bg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
  </figure>
</article>
```

CSS

```
/* Borrowed from CSS reset */

html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video, details, summary {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
        font-family: Helvetica;
}    




html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

article {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

figure img {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

jQuery - Could also be enhanced [with something like this](http://wtm.github.io/jquery.snapscroll/) to snap the viewport to each image.

Comment: Yeah this looks good except for the image not scaling proportionately (you can squash it horizontally and vertically).

Comment: Nice plugin link though, it's quite a cool effect.  I wonder how it works on mobile

Comment: The plugin works great on my 4.4.2 Android Chrome browser as long as the image is sized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
body,*{
     padding:0 !important;
     margin:0 !important;
  }
  article{
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     right:0;
   }
  .bg {
      position:relative;
   }

   .bg img {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
    }
    // your test this code
```